# d3.js: Rotating upside down link text in collapsible radial cluster

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need to fix upside down link text in the below code:

```
var clusterData = nodeData;

var clusterData = [
  {
    "name": "Level 1",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Level 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Level 3: A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Level 4: A",
                "parent": "Level 3: A",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Level 5: A",
                    "parent": "Level 4: A"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: B",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: C",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: D",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: E",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: F",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: G",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: H",
            "parent": "Level 2: A",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Level 4: C",
                "parent": "Level 3: H",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Level 5: C",
                    "parent": "Level 4: C"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: I",
            "parent": "Level 2: A",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Level 4: B",
                "parent": "Level 3: I",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Level 5: B",
                    "parent": "Level 4: B",
                      "children": [
                        {   
                            "name": "Level 6: A",
                            "parent": "Level 5: B"
                        }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: J",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: K",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: L",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: M",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: N",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: O",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: P",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: Q",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: R",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 3: S",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Level 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: C",
        "parent": "Level 1"
      },
        {
        "name": "Level 2: D",
        "parent": "Level 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: E",
        "parent": "Level 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: F",
        "parent": "Level 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: G",
        "parent": "Level 1"
      }
    ]
  }
];


var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    diameter = 1000;

var i = 0,
    duration = 350,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, 360])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth; });

var diagonal = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })

var svg = d3.select(".wrapper").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "rootSVG")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "rootG")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter/2 + "," + diameter/2 + ")")


root = clusterData[0];
root.x0 = diameter / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

root.children.forEach(collapse); // start with all children collapsed
update(root);

function update(source) {

  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 150; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click", click)

  nodeEnter.append("image")
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return d.icon ? d.icon : "/custom/customimages/NodeIcon.png";})
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return (i != 0)?"translate(0, -10)":"translate(0)"; })

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("class", "nodeLabel")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return i != 0?"rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")":"translate(0)"; })

  nodeUpdate.select("text.nodeLabel")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .style("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x > 180 ? "end":"start"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return d.x > 180 ? "rotate(180)translate(-32)":"translate(8)"; })

  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("id", function(d, i) {return "link" + i})

  function x(d) { return d.y * Math.cos((d.x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI); }
  function y(d) { return d.y * Math.sin((d.x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI); }

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
       return "M" + x(d.source) + "," + y(d.source) + "L" + x(d.target) + "," + y(d.target);
     });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .remove();

  var linkText = svg.selectAll(".linkText")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "linkText")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("dx", 60)
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#link" + i; })
      .text(function(d) { return "Relationship"; }) 

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });    
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  if(d.depth >= 4) {
    diameter = diameter + 150;
    document.getElementsByClassName("rootSVG")[0].setAttribute("width", diameter)
    document.getElementsByClassName("rootSVG")[0].setAttribute("height", diameter)
    document.getElementsByClassName("rootSVG")[0].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + diameter/2 + ", " + diameter/2 + ")")
  }


  update(d);
}

// Collapse nodes
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
        }
    }
```

If I perform a 180 degree rotation, the text goes to the other side of the radial tree. Please help.

I tried manually inserting text and rotating them, instead of using text path. However, it doesn't work after I expand the nodes. Code for that:

```
var linkText = svg.selectAll(".linkText")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "linkText")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + (d.target.x - 90) + ", 100, 0)translate(" + d.target.y/2 + ")"; })
      .append("text")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("dx", 45)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return d.target.x > 180 ?"rotate(180, 70, 0)":"rotate(0)"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.target.relationship?d.target.relationship:"Relationship"; })
```

Couldn't provide jsFiddle as it doesn't show the output for me. Any fiddle not just this one.

Comment: If I could rotate the text at it's center, would it do? But how to find it's center?

Comment: use `getBBox`, example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929

Comment: To solve your fiddle problem, try pulling it up after adding a "/result" to the end of the url. Comment a Fiddle.

Comment: Similar to Pavel's answer, you can also use `getComputedTextLength` which is seems to be quite a bit faster than `getBBox` [source](http://jsperf.com/getboundingclientrect-vs-offsetwidth/13).

Comment: @PavelGatnar Thanks mate! It's working. :)

Comment: @source, `getComputedTextLength` returns the length of the text right? How do I find the center coordinates using that?

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin, When I open the browser console for that fiddle, it shows d3 not found. Adding /result doesn't work either. Here's the fiddle. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wtL2pL5a/)

Comment: @PavelGatnar, Not working. Works only in browser console. .node() in that example returns undefined error for me. Also, if select the element using js and get it's bounding box all the values are 0.

Comment: The problem with getBBox() is it returns 0 because the element is not yet rendered in the html.

Comment: I solved it by setting a small timeout. But the text appears below the line, setting dy makes things worse.

Comment: Try loading it as an external resource.